# Using R's lm on a dataframe with a list of predictors

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with let's say N+2 columns.  The first is just dates (mainly used for plotting later on), the second is a variable whose response to the remaining N columns I would like to compute.  I'm thinking there must be something like

```
df = data.frame(y = 1:10, x1 = runif(10), x2 = rnorm(10))
fit = lm(y~df[,2:3],data=df)
```

This doesn't work.  I've also tried and failed with

`fit = lm(y~sapply(colnames(df)[2:3],as.name),data=df)`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Using the formula notation `y ~ .` specifies that you want to regress y on all of the other variables in the dataset.

```
df = data.frame(y = 1:10, x1 = runif(10), x2 = rnorm(10))
# fits a model using x1 and x2
fit <- lm(y ~ ., data = df) 
# Removes the column containing x1 so regression on x2 only
fit <- lm(y ~ ., data = df[, -2])
```

Comment: Is there a way to exclude more than one column this way?

Comment: @soandos df[,-c(3,6,7)] will exclude the 3rd, sixth, and seventh columns.

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative to Dason's answer, for when you want to specify the columns, to exclude, by name. It is to use `subset()`, and specify the `select` argument:

```
df = data.frame(y = 1:10, x1 = runif(10), x2 = rnorm(10))
fit = lm(y ~ ., data = subset(df, select=-x1))
```

Trying to use `data[,-c("x1")]` fails with "invalid argument to unary operator".

It can extend to excluding multiple columns: `subset(df, select = -c(x1,x2))`

And you can still use numeric columns:

```
df = data.frame(y = 1:10, x1 = runif(10), x2 = rnorm(10))
fit = lm(y ~ ., data = subset(df, select = -2))
```

(That is equivalent to `subset(df, select=-x1)` because `x1` is the 2nd column.)

Naturally you can also use this to specify the columns to *include*.

```
df = data.frame(y = 1:10, x1 = runif(10), x2 = rnorm(10))
fit = lm(y ~ ., data = subset(df, select=c(y,x2)) )
```

(Yes, that is equivalent to `lm(y ~ x2, df)` but is distinct if you were then going to be using `step()`, for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly new to R, but I found another way to do this for named columns in a data frame. Say you want to run regression using all columns except for column `x2`, then you'll write:

```
df = data.frame(y = 1:10, x1 = runif(10), x2 = rnorm(10))
# Removes the column containing x2 so regression on x1 only
model <- lm(Y ~ . - x2, data = df)
# to remove more columns (assuming there were more columns in the data frame)
model <- lm(Y ~ . - x2 - x3 - x4, data = df)
```

The rest of the answers are pretty old, so maybe it's a new feature, but it's pretty neat!