# Is it possible to read a list of predictor variables for lm from a list in R?

Tags: r

This question is similar to [Using R's lm on a dataframe with a list of predictors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991692/using-rs-lm-on-a-dataframe-with-a-list-of-predictors), except that I actually want to have a list of explicit predictors (that I may read from a file), because I may have thousands of predictors and I want to choose only hundreds of them at a time.

Is it possible to pass a list to the `lm` function to specify the predictors?

Comment: No. A sound course of action would be to use that list to create a formula argument.

Comment: Maybe You can use `subset` argument , something like `lm(x~.,data,subset=list_pred)`